# Jquery validation engine ajax, two fields same function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validation-engine

The jQuery validation engine plugin has the ability to do ajax validation; which works gret except for one small catch...

It sends off the field ID instead of the field name to be validated.

Why is this an issue?

I have a simple item that to create it only requires one textbox to be filled out; so we have this as a modal on every page for managing said item.

We use the jQuery validation engine plugin to validate that the entered value is unique.

Now this also means that the modal shows up on the edit page. Which obviously has the title in a field as well for you to edit.

And we want this field to be validated as well but because the validation engine sends across the field ID instead of the field name we must give the two fields different ID's

e.g. `createtitle` and `edittitle` and then on the backend have

`if($fieldId == 'createtitle' || $fieldId == 'edittitle'){$fieldId = $fieldId}`

Which really is an ugly approach; is there any way to get it to use the name; or another attribute instead?

Comment: The validating script that you are calling needs to understand which value is being passed. It doesn't matter to the validation engine. It can be used for both fields but the called script needs to know which one is being validated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this plugin](http://validatious.org/learn/getting_started) could help you. It uses class names of your element to validate.